# Run PHP function from an image hyperlink (Facemash project)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, iframe

Okay, so this is my first project using PHP and MySQL and I thought a Facemash style site using HTML, PHP and MySQL would be good place to start.

Everything works correctly except calling the "updateHits" function as an image hyperlink doesn't behave as I'd expect.

I am confident that the MySQL database is functioning correctly and the pictures do display as expected. My research points towards the use of iFrames, jQuery or AJAX to update the "hits" field although I cannot understand how to apply them here.

I hope my code is readable and any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "admin") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("facemash") or die(mysql_error());

// Select two random people
$personA = rand(1, 28);
$personB = rand(1, 28);

// Ensure that it is not the same person
if ($personB == $personA) {
   $personB = rand(1, 28);
}

// Function to return path of photo
function photoPath ($person){

$query = mysql_query("SELECT photo FROM people WHERE id=$person");
$result  = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$result = $result[0];

echo $result;
}

// Function to update the hits field
function updateHits($person){

$query = mysql_query("SELECT hits FROM people WHERE id=$person;");
$result  = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$result = $result[0];

$result++;

mysql_query("UPDATE people SET hits = $result WHERE id=$person");
}
?>

<!--Image for personA-->
<a href="<?php updateHits($personA);?>"><img src="<?php photoPath($personA);?>"/></a>

<!--Image for personB-->
<a href="<?php updateHits($personB);?>"/><img src="<?php photoPath($personB);?>"/></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erm, PHP does not work that way. ;)

PHP is serverside code, you're creating a link that points nowhere.  To get the effect you want you'll need to make an AJAX call to the server to tell it to update the hits.

Comment: Essentially what's happening when you run that code is, even though you're adding the updateHits() function inside the link, PHP parses the whole thing once and generates the output at the same time.  This means that, since updateHits($personB) doesn't actually provide any output to the browser (via print or echo or just being outside the <?php ?> tag or whatever) your finished tag looks like <a href=""/>... which pretty clearly isn't what you want.

Comment: Basically you're going to want to make a second PHP file that calls the updateHits() function with a username supplied in the URL field, and then use Javascript in your page links to load that in the background when the link is clicked and (optionally) update the loaded page to display the new data.

Comment: Thanks again, really appreciate the feedback :D

Comment: Sorry to go on but just one thing: By supplying the id in the URL, doesn't it make it really easy to game the system (by someone manually entering the same URL to increase their number of hits). Any thoughts on how to avoid this?

Comment: It is very easy to game, yes.  That's why you should memorize one thing before you go any further: Never trust user input.  :)

Comment: What this means is that any interface you provide WILL be abused to the utmost possible degree.  Anything you let the browser do can be automatically repeated indefinitely at thousands of times per second, so you'll need to get creative.  Limit hits by IP, for example - then subsequent (fraudulent) hits won't be worth beans.